# How can I save multiple IP addresses from file names in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash

Pretty new to Bash, I'm working on a bash script to automate storing/retrieving certificates from a certain directory.  I figured out how to get one IP, but if there are multiple files with IP addresses in a directory, I am unsure how to store a list of the IPs.

For example, I can look in a directory whose path is saved in ${PATH}
`PATH=$(ls path/to/directory)`
 to get ONLY the IP from a file named 0.0.0.0Cert.pem

`SINGLE_IP=${echo "PATH%%C%"}`

SINGLE_IP == 0.0.0.0

But if there is a 0.0.0.0Cert.pem and a 1.1.1.1Cert.pem in ${PATH}

`SINGLE_IP=${echo "PATH%%C%"}` 
will only get the first IP found in the directory, however, I need to get all the IPs so I can grab all the relevant files later in the script.

Thanks!

EDIT:

For clarity I ONLY need the IP from the file names. I don't need the Cert.pem or anything other than the actual IP.

Comment: So the files you are looking for are stored in a single directory?

Comment: Yes. We can assume there are at least 2 files with IPs in a common directory and I need to get all of them.

Answer (score 3):

With **`find`** command:

To find the "crucial" files:

```
find path/to/dir -type f -name *[0-9]Cert.pem
```

---

To extract only IP addresses from filenames:

```
find path/to/dir -type f -name "*[0-9]Cert.pem" -exec sh -c \
     'f=$(basename $1);  echo "${f%Cert*}"' _ {} \;
```

The output would be in the following format:

```
0.0.0.0
1.1.1.1
...
```

Comment: Thank you, but maybe I was a little unclear. I can get the file names with Cert.pem attached. But what I need is a way to save ONLY the IP from the filenames, so that I can save them in a key/value store under that IP address.

Comment: Elaborate, dude. I don't see how this solution fails to meet your expressed needs.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed RomanPerekhrest.  To get all the IPs that are in the filenames within a directory.  Thanks for your timely response yesterday.